# Using params with ref keyword in C#

Tags: c#, .net, parameter-passing, ref

I want to pass a variable number of arguments to a function so I used `params` keyword, but I also want to pass those arguments as reference. I tried by adding the `ref` keyword but Visual Studio shows

> The params parameter can not be declared as ref or out.

Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments as reference? If not, then why?

```
public bool fbRemoveLastSeparator(params ref string[] sInputStrings)
{
    try
    {
        foreach(string str in sInputStrings)
        {
            //do something
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `params` stands for?

Comment: @sujithkarivelil It is for a dynamic number of arguments of same type. So you can call e.g. `method(param1, param2)` as well as `method(param1, param2, param3, ... , paramN)` and have only one method handling all of those.

Comment: By using the params keyword, you can specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.

Comment: @Fildor: thank you, it's a new information for me. I haven't tried that yet

Comment: @sujithkarivelil You can read this for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Comment: It depends on your particular use case, but could you just use a method signature of (ref List<string> sInputStrings) instead of (params ref string[] sInputStrings). The internals of the method, if mutating your list objects, would still give the desired effect?